# Finding Rank and Nullity of a Linear Transform

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:R^5 \rightarrow R^5$ be a Linear Transformation such that $T^4(x) = 0$. Then show that rankT = 3 and nullity T = 2.

There is no other information provided. Starting with T(0) = 0 as T is LT, I am not able to make considerable headway. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$T=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

is such that $T^4=0$ but nullity is not $2$..

Comment: I feel some information is missing in the question perhaps. Could it be that?

Comment: I think some thing is missing... Forcing $T^3\neq 0$ would give some better answer..